Is it possible the spinor in a fermionic wavefunction is just a frame-dependent transformation to an invariant object?
The suggestion in the title, as far as I know, is attributable to David Hestenes, for example on page 8 of this paper, although I imagine he laid it out more explicitly in some earlier papers.  The point is that, via the geometric algebra over spacetime, the Dirac spinor can be interpreted as a transformation which is applied via conjugation; quoting from the section,
$$\Psi = \rho^\frac12 R e^{i\beta}$$
which can be interpreted as a composition of dilation, Lorentz transformation, and duality rotation, as explained in this Phys.SE post for example.  Hestenes shows that, given a reference vector field, such as the unit time vector $\gamma_0$ for the given reference frame, this transformation produces another vector field, $v$, and what's fascinating is that $v$ is invariant; that is, even though both $\gamma_0$ and $\Psi$ depend on the reference frame, and in particular $\gamma_0$ transforms as a vector whereas $\Psi$ transforms as a spinor and undergoes a double cover, their combination via conjugation results in a fixed vector field.
Now, to me it might even make more sense to go with a bivector field rather than a vector field, as that would make full use of the spinor -- the $e^{i\beta}$ ends up canceling out when applied to a vector, whereas it would act as the duality rotation on a bivector.  (In this case, the reference field might be e.g. the unit $xy$ bivector in all reference frames.)  In either case, the challenge is then to find some meaning in the invariant geometric field.  Regardless, I'll stick with the name $v$ for the invariant field, whatever its type.
Irrespective of that point, however, my question is whether interpreting $\Psi$ as a mere transformation can be compatible with all other quantum theoretical considerations.  For example, with multiple fermions, why should it be their wavefunctions that are orthogonal, rather than the invariant fields to which those functions "point"?  In a similar vein, why should e.g. the Dirac equation be linear with respect to $\Psi$ rather than $v$, when summation and conjugation of spinors do not commute?  And what about the gauge fields: these would seem to take away our ability to say exactly what transformation $\Psi$ even is; for example, the $U(1)$ gauge covariant derivative around a closed loop can effectively change the phase of $\Psi$, such that it doesn't have a well-defined value.
But I'm playing devil's advocate here precisely because this notion of an invariant field is so alluring, and it seems worthwhile to understand if it is fully viable.  Here we have the chance to resolve the mystery of the double cover, AND a reason for the squared norm of the wavefunction being the quantity that is normalized, as $|\Psi|^2$ is the magnitude of invariant field $v$ (despite arguably still lacking an explanation for normalization as a general requirement).
I imagine it would be hard to prove decisively that it is a foolproof interpretation, so maybe I'm just checking if there are any reasons, either one that I listed or perhaps a different one, that are clear deal-breakers for this way of viewing the fermionic wavefunction.

I'm really not sure what it is you are getting so confused and hyped up about. It should be obvious, if not stated exactly by Hestenes, that $\Psi$ converts any coördinate time vector $\gamma^0$ to the time vector of the rest frame of the electron itself, which looks like $v$ in the original coördinate frame. Another part does the spin-half rotation. The $\rho$ is not a dilation, but obviously is the probability density of finding the electron at that point. It cannot be a dilation because it is not stretching or squishing spacetime.
